# Is it possible to include CHE on existing docker-compose file?

Tags: eclipse-che

in my company we use our docker-compose to build our development enviroment with php, mysql, apache, xdebug, behat, drush and so on.. (we mainly develop Drupal sites) I was wandering if it is possible to load also Eclipse Che to use the IDE in my existing setting? I think the answer is no.. because from what i can understand CHE comes with his stacks, or maybe i'm wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. Here's a template that Che CLI uses to generate a composefile https://github.com/eclipse/che/blob/master/dockerfiles/init/modules/compose/templates/docker-compose.yml.erb

```
 che:
    image: eclipse/che-server:nightly
    mem_limit: 750m
    memswap_limit: 0
    env_file:
      - '/data/instance/config/che/che.env'
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
      - '/home/eugene/Documents/chesag/instance/data:/data'
      - '/home/eugene/Documents/chesag/instance/logs:/logs'
      - '/home/eugene/Documents/chesag/instance/config/che:/conf'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    restart: always
    container_name: che
```

Host paths in volume bind mounts should be your actual host paths.

Comment: Thanks! I can see the dashboard, but it's stuck in loading the page
https://gyazo.com/b00b9592b8c49b728bba86cbb022966a  

I see the error  

`Websockets
No reply of websocket test after 5 seconds. Websocket is failing to connect to ws://myurl.local:8080/api/ws`  
  
In the diagnosics, any hint?  

Just to clarify i'm running docker in a ubuntu VM